# How can I access query string in AWS lambda using Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, parameters, aws-lambda

I am having trouble accessing query strings in AWS lambda. I created body mapping template for method request passthrough in integration settings of API gateway but still no resolve. I am working with the following code.

```
from __future__ import print_function

from urlparse import parse_qs
import boto3
import json

print('Loading function')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return event.get('params')
```

**Edit: added mapping template.**

```
##  See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html
##  This template will pass through all parameters including path, querystring, header, stage variables, and context through to the integration endpoint via the body/payload
#set($allParams = $input.params())
{
"body-json" : "$input.json('$')",
"params" : {
#foreach($type in $allParams.keySet())
    #set($params = $allParams.get($type))
"$type" : {
    #foreach($paramName in $params.keySet())
    "$paramName" : "$util.escapeJavaScript($params.get($paramName))"
        #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
    #end
}
    #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
#end
},
"stage-variables" : {
#foreach($key in $stageVariables.keySet())
"$key" : "$util.escapeJavaScript($stageVariables.get($key))"
    #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
#end
},
"context" : {
    "account-id" : "$context.identity.accountId",
    "api-id" : "$context.apiId",
    "api-key" : "$context.identity.apiKey",
    "authorizer-principal-id" : "$context.authorizer.principalId",
    "caller" : "$context.identity.caller",
    "cognito-authentication-provider" : "$context.identity.cognitoAuthenticationProvider",
    "cognito-authentication-type" : "$context.identity.cognitoAuthenticationType",
    "cognito-identity-id" : "$context.identity.cognitoIdentityId",
    "cognito-identity-pool-id" : "$context.identity.cognitoIdentityPoolId",
    "http-method" : "$context.httpMethod",
    "stage" : "$context.stage",
    "source-ip" : "$context.identity.sourceIp",
    "user" : "$context.identity.user",
    "user-agent" : "$context.identity.userAgent",
    "user-arn" : "$context.identity.userArn",
    "request-id" : "$context.requestId",
    "resource-id" : "$context.resourceId",
    "resource-path" : "$context.resourcePath"
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your mapping template mapped to the correct content-type being submitted in your request? Show your mapping template.

Comment: Yes - content-type is `application/json` Just added mapping template.

Comment: After thinking through your question again, I realized the request to endpoint did not have correct `content-type` header. :)